# defining a custom special-block

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to define my own interpretor for [special blocks](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-special-blocks.html) for a custom backend.

I've written this sort of thing, mostly copy/pasting from the `src-block` interpreter

```
(defun org-leanpub-special-block (special-block contents info)
  (replace-regexp-in-string
   "^" "A> "
   (org-remove-indentation
    (org-element-property :value special-block))))
```

I've also registered it as a translator and it's being called.

The goal is that this

```
#+BEGIN_aside
/wibble/
wibble
I'm a fish
#+END_aside
```

will be rendered as

```
A> *wibble*
A> wibble
A> I'm a fish
```

(note that the text is processed by the usual processor, which is derived from markdown).

But the debugger is kicking in with

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "^" "A> " (org-remove-indentation (org-element-property :value special-block)))
```

which would imply that my call to `org-element-property` is not doing what I thought. So how do I get the rendered version of the `special-block` body?

(I plan on switching on the `TYPE` of special block, but one step at a time...)

Comment: ooh, I found `org-html-special-block` and reading for inspiration

Answer (score 3):

oh, I'm an idiot

```
(defun org-leanpub-special-block (special-block contents info)
  (replace-regexp-in-string
   "^" "A> " contents))
```

and now I can consider switching on the type of block, falling back to `org-html-special-block`.